# Python/pyside2 how to iterate 5 times, then add a row and then iterate again?

Tags: python, for-loop, pyside2, qtwidgets, qgridlayout

I'm populating a QtWidgets.QGridLayout from a large list and I'm trying to create a loop that will add one row with 5 columns, over and over again, until I run out of things in a list.

Here is a example of what my broken brain is struggling with...

```
mylist =['thing001', 'thing002', 'thing003', 'thing004', 'thing005', 'thing006', 'thing007', 'thing008', 'thing009', 'thing010']

rowCount=0
colCount=0

def start():
   
    for each in mylist:
        i=0
        myThing = (str('btn_'+ each ))
        colCount=0
        rowCount=0
    
        #add a column until it reaches 5, then make a new row?
        for i in range(0,5):
            colCount += 1
            i+=1
            print ('Making Thing: ' + myThing +' | '+(str(rowCount)+':'+(str(colCount))))

        else:
            print('New Row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            colCount = 0
            rowCount += 1
            i+=1
                
start()
```

which gives me this...

```
Making Thing: btn_thing001 | 0:1
Making Thing: btn_thing001 | 0:2
Making Thing: btn_thing001 | 0:3
Making Thing: btn_thing001 | 0:4
Making Thing: btn_thing001 | 0:5
New Row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Making Thing: btn_thing002 | 0:1
Making Thing: btn_thing002 | 0:2
Making Thing: btn_thing002 | 0:3
Making Thing: btn_thing002 | 0:4
Making Thing: btn_thing002 | 0:5
New Row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

which I would like to be...

```
Making Thing: btn_thing001 | 0:1
Making Thing: btn_thing002 | 0:2
Making Thing: btn_thing003 | 0:3
Making Thing: btn_thing004 | 0:4
Making Thing: btn_thing005 | 0:5
New Row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Making Thing: btn_thing006 | 1:1
Making Thing: btn_thing007 | 1:2
Making Thing: btn_thing008 | 1:3
Making Thing: btn_thing009 | 1:4
Making Thing: btn_thing010 | 1:5
New Row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

How do I structure the loops to spit out what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do using the python built-in function [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

```
mylist = ['thing001', 'thing002', 'thing003', 'thing004', 'thing005', 'thing006', 'thing007', 'thing008', 'thing009', 'thing010']
COLUMNS = 5

for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
    row, column = divmod(i, COLUMNS)
    print(item, row, column)
```

print output:

```
thing001 0 0
thing002 0 1
thing003 0 2
thing004 0 3
thing005 0 4
thing006 1 0
thing007 1 1
thing008 1 2
thing009 1 3
thing010 1 4
```

Comment: You missed out the `New Row!!!` output lines.

Comment: In the end it's about populating a `QGridLayout`, so you only need the coordinates. I'm sure the prints are only for debugging.